# Verifying user log email and password by looping through psql table

Tags: javascript, html, postgresql, knex.js

I am learning to code and am attempting to build a to do web application in node using Express (I think that's the right wording).

I have a table('users') in postgresql which stores user_id,email and password.

When a user logs in to the website I want to loop through the table and ensure the email exists and it matches the password and then the user can log in and when they're logged in - their unique user_id is assigned and brings up their previous to do lists.. I would like to incorporate knex also if possible.

I am at a loss how to do this and would appreciate any tips/pointing in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: This is a simple SELECT query, what have you tried and what issues are you facing?

Answer (score 0):

Try something basic first

```
SELECT
  user_id
  FROM users
  WHERE
   email = _your_user_email
   AND password = _your_user_password;
```

If the result you get back contains user_id or whatever you want returned, then the user exists. You can expand on this further by checking for email, and let the user know that the email exists but the password is incorrect, etc. Try the simple method first and see if this meet your need.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would recommend you to name your `id` field for your `users` table as `id`.
It is best practice to name `id` fields as `id` and reference columns as `<tablename>_id`
(eg. table `clothes.id` unique identifier for iter and `clothes.user_id` – foreign key to table `users`).

Secondly, it is highly **NOT** recommended to store your passwords as raw data inside of the database (security reasons).
It is a common practice to keep user passwords as hashed data.
For example, take a look at [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs) package.

To select users (there is no such thing as "loop" in terms of database, it is called "query") you need to
create a query like

```
select
    id,
    email,
    <any_other_field_you_need>
from
    users
where
    email = 'your@email.com'
    and password = 'your password hash'
```

In terms of `knex` it can be written

```
knex('users')
    .select(['id', 'email', '<any_other_field_you_need>'])
    .where('email', 'your@email.com')
    .where('password', 'your password hash')
```

Your query params (email, password) you can get from express [body](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body).
Make sure you are using POST HTTP method to send your request and pass your data as a body.

In case you don't know `express` – it's an [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express).
It helps in the creation of web-services. They have a hello world [guide](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html) on their
official website. Feel free to check it out. Or just simply google "express tutorial for beginner" there are a lot of great tutorials over the internet about it. It's quite popular.